# sudo -E env PATH=$PATH

Tags: shell, sudo, environment-variables

What does the following command do exactly?

```
sudo -E env PATH=$PATH
```

I can't get a hold of a simplistic meaning to what this does.

I know that `-E` passes the users which is invoking `sudo` environmental variables, however the `env`?

Comment: In your command line, `env` isn't a parameter to `sudo`, it's the start of the command that's being sudoed. Look up `man env`. I can't see that it's doing anything because `env` sets environment variables and then executes a command ... without a command it just prints the resulting environment. Could it be something to do with copying the current user's PATH to or from root's?

Answer (score 1):

In this context `env` prints the environment variables, using a custom `PATH` value that is interpolated by the shell before `sudo` is run and passed along through `sudo` in the arguments list. Given that `-E` should preserve the environment**  setting `PATH` via the arguments to what `sudo` should pass through via the environment seems redundant, though with `sudo ... env PATH="$PATH" cmd ...` one could ensure that `cmd ...` is run with a specific `PATH` setting free of any possible manglement by `sudo`.

** [What preserve means will vary depending on the release of `sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/d4dfb05db5d7) given that `sudo` as of 2016 or so retains the first environment variable of any duplicates versus `bash` and other programs using the final of any duplicate environment variables.

Comment: `sudo` sets `$PATH` to the `secure_path` setting which is why it makes sense to use `sudo -E env PATH="$PATH" cmd` or `sudo -E PATH="$PATH" cmd` (note the missing quotes in the OP's variant though)